# How can I simply use pure Mingw GCC after installing MSYS(2)?

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, msys2

So I've been reading online but I'm still very confused. I understand that there are different tools in the Linux-on-Windows world: Msys, Msys2, Cygwin, Mingw and Mingw-64.

Here is what I think I know, and please correct me if I'm wrong:

1. Mingw aims to simply be a port of the GCC programs to Windows. It creates native Windows binaries and that's it.
2. Mingw-64 is just a more recent and better supported version of Mingw that also supports Windows 64 bit.
3. Cygwin, while also including Mingw (?) to support GCC on Windows, provides a POSIX compatibility layer through a DLL that all programs are linked to by default.
4. MSYS is a fork of Cygwin, but it drops some of the POSIX compatibility efforts. Instead it mostly aims to allow creating native Windows program. But - they will still be dependent on a MSYS DLL being present.
5. MSYS2 is just a more recent and active version of the less active MSYS.

Is this all true? If it is, here is what I want to validate:

Essentially, I think all I should need for my development is Mingw in order to use GCC to build native Windows applications. I don't need a POSIX layer, and I *don't* want my program to depend on any DLL apart from the ones that are present on Windows systems anyway. As far as I understand, this is what Mingw offers.

However, somehow I managed to install MSYS (or MSYS2? I'm not sure anymore) on my system. The tutorial I was following early on suggested doing so.

Since it seems MSYS(2) includes Mingw under `C:\msys64\mingw64`, I just use the Mingw binaries directly from the Windows CMD without going through the MSYS(2) shell program. For example, I just added `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` to the `PATH` and I run `gcc` from the Windows CMD directly to compile my project.

1. Is this a valid way to use Mingw? Or am I expected to run into problems?
2. Does this approach create pure Windows native binaries which should never depend on any MSYS(2)-related DLL?
3. Is it true that the MSYS(2)-related functionality and dependencies only come into play if I launch the Mingw programs (such as GCC) through the *msys2.exe shell program*? And so if I want to avoid any MSYS(2) or Cygwin related stuff, and simply use pure Mingw GCC, is it an okay approach to just launch GCC directly under the Mingw directory as described earlier?

**Update:** I have now checked using Dependency Walker, and running `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc` from the MSYS2 shell still creates an `.exe` with no special dependencies (which is good). So what is this `msys-2.0.dll` that the MSYS2 docs speak of? And how is using MSYS2 to compile C different than just using Mingw?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mostly right about what these projects are.  MSYS2 does provide an evironment for POSIX programs like Bash, GNU Make, and other utilities, but it also provides a package manager named pacman that you can use to install lots of other things.  In fact, you can use pacman to install a mingw-w64 toolchain.

MSYS2 provides two mingw-w64 toolchains actually: you get a choice of an i686 (32-bit) toolchain which makes native Windows binaries that can run on any Windows computer, or an x86_64 (64-bit) toolchain that makes native Windows binaries that only work on 64-bit Windows.  You can install both of these at the same time.

You say "I don't need a POSIX layer", but you might find it useful to be able to write Bash scripts or use POSIX programs provided by MSYS2 like GNU Make when building your native Windows software.   This is especially useful if you want to someday build your software on Linux or macOS: it's possible to write a simple Makefile or shell script that works on those platforms and also MSYS2.

1. Yes, it's valid to use the binaries from `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` directly if you want to.
2. Yes, the mingw-w64 toolchain creates native Windows binaries regardless of which shell you happen to run it from.
3. No.  Whether you start MSYS2 via msys2.exe, mingw32.exe, or mingw64.exe, you get a Bash shell with various Linux utilities available like `ls`, `grep`, `make`, and `tar`.  The shell and those utilities use the POSIX emulation provided by msys-2.0.dll.  The main difference between those MSYS2 launchers is what gets added to your PATH, so you might want to run `echo $PATH` and `env` in each of those environments and compare the results.

Comment: gmake and bash scripts can be used from the MSYS2 shell, while still targeting native Windows.  When OP says "I don't need a POSIX layer"  I assume they are talking about programs that they are building

Comment: Yes, indeed I meant that I don't want the program I'm building to depend on any DLL apart from the Windows DLLs. You answered this in points 1 and 2 - I can use the mingw64 binaries directly and they will simply produce native Windows programs with no additional dependencies. Thanks! I'm accepting your answer, but you might want to clarify or correct the last point in relation to the question for others to not be mislead.

Comment: How do I make linux/mingw binaries in mingw?

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly recommend using MSYS2 instead of MSYS and mingw.org . Pretend those latter two don't even exist. Being under active development the newer projects are better in every way.

MSYS2's package manager can deliver toolchains for the following target systems:

- Standalone Win32 (i686)
- Standalone Win64 (x86_64)
- MSYS2 i686
- MSYS2 x86_64

The former two cases can be invoked from any shell you like. You may need to set up paths if not using the launch script provided by MSYS2. They produce native Windows executables.  Using the default switches to GCC there will be some dependencies, such as `libgcc_s*.dll` .  Doing a static build with `-static` will produce an executable with no dependencies other than Windows DLLs.

In the latter two cases, the binary will depend on the MSYS2 DLL, and other things, but this provides support for a range of POSIX functionality.

```
[~ MSYS]$ ls /usr/include
_ansi.h            cursesp.h      glob.h         net           strings.h
_newlib_version.h  cursesw.h      gnumake.h      netdb.h       symcat.h
_syslist.h         cursslk.h      grp.h          netinet       sys
a.out.h            cygwin         icmp.h         newlib.h      sysexits.h
acl                devctl.h       ieeefp.h       nl_types.h    syslog.h
aio.h              diagnostics.h  ifaddrs.h      panel.h       tar.h
alloca.h           dirent.h       inttypes.h     paths.h       term.h
alpm.h             dis-asm.h      io.h           plugin-api.h  term_entry.h
alpm_list.h        dlfcn.h        langinfo.h     poll.h        termcap.h
ansidecl.h         elf.h          lastlog.h      process.h     termio.h
ar.h               endian.h       libfdt.h       pthread.h     termios.h
argz.h             envlock.h      libfdt_env.h   pty.h         tgmath.h
arpa               envz.h         libgen.h       pwd.h         threads.h
asm                err.h          limits.h       reent.h       tic.h
assert.h           errno.h        locale.h       regdef.h      time.h
attr               error.h        machine        regex.h       tzfile.h
bfd.h              eti.h          magic.h        resolv.h      ucontext.h
bfd_stdint.h       etip.h         malloc.h       sched.h       unctrl.h
bfdlink.h          fastmath.h     mapi.h         search.h      unistd.h
bits               fcntl.h        math.h         semaphore.h   utime.h
byteswap.h         fdt.h          memory.h       setjmp.h      utmp.h
complex.h          features.h     menu.h         signal.h      utmpx.h
cpio.h             fenv.h         mntent.h       spawn.h       w32api
ctf.h              FlexLexer.h    monetary.h     ssp           wait.h
ctf-api.h          fnmatch.h      mqueue.h       stdatomic.h   wchar.h
ctype.h            form.h         nc_tparm.h     stdint.h      wctype.h
curses.h           fts.h          ncurses        stdio.h       winpty
cursesapp.h        ftw.h          ncurses.h      stdio_ext.h   wordexp.h
cursesf.h          gawkapi.h      ncurses_dll.h  stdlib.h      xlocale.h
cursesm.h          getopt.h       ncursesw       string.h
[~ MSYS]$
[~ MSYS]$
[~ MSYS]$ ls /usr/include/sys
_default_fcntl.h  acl.h          fcntl.h     mman.h    quota.h     signal.h      stdio.h      termio.h    ttychars.h  utsname.h
_intsup.h         cdefs.h        features.h  mount.h   random.h    signalfd.h    strace.h     termios.h   types.h     vfs.h
_pthreadtypes.h   config.h       file.h      msg.h     reent.h     smallprint.h  string.h     time.h      ucontext.h  wait.h
_sigset.h         custom_file.h  iconvnls.h  mtio.h    resource.h  socket.h      sysinfo.h    timeb.h     uio.h       xattr.h
_stdint.h         cygwin.h       ioctl.h     param.h   sched.h     soundcard.h   syslimits.h  timerfd.h   un.h
_timespec.h       dir.h          ipc.h       poll.h    select.h    stat.h        syslog.h     times.h     unistd.h
_timeval.h        dirent.h       kd.h        procfs.h  sem.h       statfs.h      sysmacros.h  timespec.h  utime.h
_types.h          errno.h        lock.h      queue.h   shm.h       statvfs.h     sysproto.h   tree.h      utmp.h
```

Cygwin is a competing product also providing POSIX functions and depending on a Cygwin DLL. The MSYS2 target is a fork of Cygwin.

Comment: I used the mingw64 GCC directly to build an `.exe`. Using Dependency Walker, it doesn't seem to depend on any DLL apart from normal Windows DLLs.  I don't see a dependency on `libgcc_s*.dll` for example. Are you sure about that?

Comment: @AvivCohn perhaps your program was simple and didn't use any features from those DLLs. You can also test dependencies by just launching the program outside of the msys2 shell (where required DLLs will not be found)

Comment: It's weird, because the docs on libgcc say it's called for really common simple tasks, like floating point math. And my program isn't exceptionally small, it is 5000 LoC. Hmmm. Any thoughts on this? Btw, if the program indeed does depend on libgcc, does this mean anytime I build something with GCC to distribute to other machines, I need to statically include libgcc?

Comment: Couldn't say sorry . You could try building with and without `-static` and comparing symbol tables, or something